# How to add column dynamically in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I want to include column in where clause depending on the condition. 
e.g
select * From emp
where id=7,
and if(code is not null) then code=8;

how can i do this in sql server

Comment: do you mean... SELECT field1, CASE WHEN code is not null THEN 8 ELSE null END as code, field3 FROM emp where id=7;

Comment: What is `code`? Is it a column?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correct, you could make use of COALESCE.

[COALESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

> Returns the first nonnull expression
>   among its arguments.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    emp
WHERE   id=7
        AND code = COALESCE(@code, code)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `code` is a column rather than a variable the query in your question would be rewritten as follows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp 
WHERE id=7 AND (code IS NULL OR code=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to create a query dynamically, as a string, and then use the Execute method to actually execute it. This approach has some potentially optimization issues, but it's commonly done. You might wan to Google `T-SQL Dynamic Query`, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

here is the example:

```
declare @SQL varchar(500)
declare @var1 int
set int = 1
set @SQL = 'Select * from ABC Where 1 = 1'

if(@var1 = 1)
set @SQL + @SQL ' And column1 = ' @var1

exec(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also use this in case of Null value in @var1.

Select * from ABC where Column1 = isNull(@var1, Column1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE function.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I don't know if i understood your question, but i guess that you want to include the value of the code column in the results.

If i'm right it can be done in the select part instead of the where clause. i. e.

```
Select ..., case when code is not null then 8 else code end as code from emp where id = 7
```

The other interpretation is that you want to filter rows where code <> 8,that would be

```
Select * from emp where id = 7 and (code is null OR code = 8)
```